# Error: 0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

Tags: reactjs, npm, https, yarnpkg, pem

I clone a project to start working on and after yarn install and yarn start https, I am getting a Error: 0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line...

Someone else created the project and I don't have very much details about it. I am suppose to just get it up and running. But I can't. I really don't even know what the error message means.

After google some time looks like somthing to do with a PEM file or cert. How can I figure out what is needed for to fix that error message?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue, I spent around 1 week working on this and still no solution for my M1 Mac Pro.

Solved my problem by:

1. Search for your .npmrc file and delete it.
   `sudo find ~ -type f -name '*npmrc'`
   `rm -rf /Users/<user>/.npmrc`
2. Do some classics like:
   `npm cache verify`
   `npm cache clear --force`
3. Finally use the npm install

Hope it helps, at least for the future user :DD